# Visual studio creates local copy of assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, telerik, .net-assembly

I have the problem, that Visual Studio creates a local copy of all telerik assemblies, wether they are referenced or not (to the bin\Debug directory).
All other assemblies were not copied from visual studio during the build process,
which is the expected behaviour.

I have already proofed the 'local copy' attribute for every single assembly.

Is there any thing i don't know about local copies of asssemblies?

Thank you!

Comment: How would we know what you don't know about local copies of assemblies?

Comment: Good question ;) I only know, that i can turn the setting on and off for every referenced assembly. And it is turned off for all telerik assemblies.